# Google Sheets Arrayformula with exceptions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am using fantastic `Arrayformula` to populate a grid in a Google Sheet:

[image]

The following is being used in each column: `=arrayformula(if(Z2:Z <> "","■",""))`

Now there are some cases where the marking "square" could be inserted manually, however this will break the Arrayformula as it cannot overwrite.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: you want to achieve what? not breaking arayformula after you break it manually?

Comment: what about dropping that arrayformula and using one-cell-solution: =if($Z2 <> "","■","")

Comment: What about pasting as values then make the manual changes?

Comment: @Rubén could you expand your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the formula by its results by using copy & "paste as values".

1. Select the area of the fantastic `ArrayFormula` results.
2. Click on Edit > Copy
3. Click on Edit > Paste special > Paste values only

Now you could add edit the any cell in the range without losing the values originally retrieved by the fantastic `ArrayFormula`.

Related Q&A

- [Allow data from IMPORTRANGE to be overwritten](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87235/88163)

Comment: the above answer works. the problem though is that the new information will be static. if the source spreadsheet is edited, the destination information will not be updated.